# Python code went wrong for my optimization problem

Tags: python

I am new in using python. I tried to write a code for my optimization research model. Could you help me please? I don't know what's wrong with the code. I am using python 2 by the way. Thank you.

```
for i in range(len(lift)):

 prob+=lpSum(dec_var[i])<=1

#constraints

col_con=[1,0,0,2,2,3,1,1]

dec_var=np.array(dec_var)

col_data=[]

for j in range(len(brands)):

 col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var)[j]))

 prob+=lpSum(col_data[j])<=col_con[j]

#problem

prob.writeLP("SO.lp")

#solve the problem

prob.solve()

print("The maximum Total lift obtained is:",value(prob.objective)) # print the output

#print the decision variable output matrix

Matrix=[[0 for X in range(len(lift[0]))] for y in range(len(lift))]

for v in prob.variables():

 Matrix[int(v.name.split("_")[2])][int(v.name.split("_")[3])]=v.varValue

 matrix=np.int_(Matrix)

print ("The decision variable matrix is:")

print(matrix)
```

### the error was :

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        13 for j in range(len(brands)):
>        14 
>   ---> 15  col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var)[j]))
>        16 
>        17  prob+=lpSum(col_data[j])<=col_con[j]
>
> TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ```col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var)[j]))``` should be ```col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var))[j])```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify what exactly the issue is. Have you done any debugging? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.

Comment: @AMC I agree that variables should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` format, but `CamelCase` is completely acceptable in python. It doesn't affect the running of python at all.

Comment: @TheMaker _It doesn't affect the running of python at all._ It wasn't my intention to imply that is the case.

Comment: @AMC Then the user can use `CamelCase` all he wants!

Comment: @TheMaker I never said he couldn't, I just mentioned it because far too many people are not aware of that convention.

Comment: @AMC I agree. I personally use the method you say, but the other is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code breaks in this line:

```
col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var)[j]))
```

Lets go through it step by step:
dec_var is an array, probably with multiple dimensions. Something like this:

```
dec_var=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
dec_var
#array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

The star operator (*) breaks the array into 'variables'. Something more or less like this:
a = [1,2,3,4], b = [5,6,7,8].
('a' and 'b' don't really exist, just trying to paint a picture).

Next, you apply zip(), which allows you to iterate two iterables together. You would usually use it like this:

```
for i,j in zip([1,2],[3,4]):
    print(i,j)
#1,3
#2,4
```

However, zip itself is not subscriptable, that is the error you are getting.

To make it subscriptable, you can apply list on it.

```
list(zip([1,2],[3,4]))[0]
#(1,3)
```

In other words.. The solution to your problem most likely is changing the position of the [j] subscript:

From:

```
col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var)[j]))
```

To:

```
col_data.append(list(zip(*dec_var))[j])
```

Comment: @ummishaqilah if the solution above worked for you please consider marking it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: hi. it works. but the line after that caused a problem when i run. The prob+=lpSum(col_data[j])<=col_con[j] . How can i fix it ?